# Change MAC address

Tags: c#

I've searched a lot on the internet and couldn't find a very good answer.

What I've tried:

I've tried to change the MAC address from registry programmatically but all of my methods failed.

This is my code

```
 private string readMAC()
    {
        RegistryKey rkey;
        string MAC;
        rkey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Class\\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\\0012", true); //--->this is the string to change 
        MAC = (string)rkey.GetValue("NetworkAddress");
        rkey.Close();
        return MAC;
    }
```

I use win 10 but it's important to change this mac on every Windows like Win server and win 8,7

Comment: This is the code to read the MAC address. Can you show what you've tried to change it?

Comment: Isn't a MAC address part of the hardware and thus unchangeable?

Comment: i try to change registry key but don't work at all @MichaelGunter

Comment: there are a lot program that change mac address @rory.ap

Comment: "every Windows", but this is tagged with OS X?

Comment: sorry i edit my answer ! @crashmstr

Comment: https://github.com/angusshire/mac-spoofer ... you also need "Admin" rights to be able to open the registry key, and write to it. You can find c# wrapper classes to access WMI.

Comment: i try that @ColinSmith

Comment: @rory.ap the default address is but almost every modern network driver I have seen on any OS allows you to override it. For example, here is where in the GUI you can set it for the Intel driver https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKrhK.png Also Mohammad, that Registery key is driver specific, setting the key on another machine that uses a diffrent brand network card won't work.

Comment: yes i could change my mac-address  manually. but i couldn't found any idea for change mac-address with C#  @rory.ap

Comment: @MohammadHosseinjfp you need to edit your question and explain in more detail about what goes wrong when it "doesn't work". If you get a exception you need to include the excption details. If you can set the value but nothing changes when you check you need to explain that. You need to go in to detail about how it goes wrong if you want us to help you.

Comment: ok edit my question immediately  @ScottChamberlain